# How, in R, can you create a cross table from a named num based on its names?

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector with names following a pattern. The name for each element consists of two parts. There are a fixed number of variations on the first part and a fixed number of variations on the second part per the below.

```
x <- c(2, 4, 3, 7, 6, 9)
names(x) <- c("a.0", "b.0", "c.0", "a.1", "b.1", "c.1")
```

From this I want to create and print a table where the first part of the names is the rows and the second part the columns per the below.

```
   a   b   c
0  2   4   3
1  7   6   9
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some possibilities. The first 3 only use base R.

**1) tapply** Use `tapply` with the row and column parts specified in the second argument.

```
nms <- names(x)
tapply(x, list(row = sub(".*\\.", "", nms), col = sub("\\..*", "", nms)), c)
```

giving the following matrix with the indicated row and column names.

```
   col
row a b c
  0 2 4 3
  1 7 6 9
```

**2) xtabs** Another possibility is to use `xtabs`:

```
dnms <- read.table(text = names(x), sep = ".", as.is = TRUE, 
  col.names = c("col", "row"))[2:1]
xtabs(x ~ ., dnms)
```

giving this xtabs/table object:

```
   col
row a b c
  0 2 4 3
  1 7 6 9
```

**3) reshape**

```
long <- cbind(x, read.table(text = names(x), sep = ".", as.is = TRUE, 
  col.names = c("col", "row")))
r <- reshape(long, dir = "wide", idvar = "row", timevar = "col")[-1]
dimnames(r) <- lapply(long[3:2], unique)

r
```

giving this data.frame:

```
  a b c
0 2 4 3
1 7 6 9
```

**4) dplyr/tidyr/tibble**  Using the indicated packages we can form the following pipeline:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

x %>%
  stack %>%
  separate(ind, c("col", "rowname")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = ".") %>%
  column_to_rownames
```

giving this data.frame:

```
  a b c
0 2 4 3
1 7 6 9
```

If you are using an older version of tidyr replace the `pivot_wider` line with

```
spread(col, values) %>%
```

As per @d.b. comment this would also work:

```
x %>% 
  data.frame %>%
  rownames_to_column  %>%
  separate(rowname, c("col", "rowname")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = ".") %>%
  column_to_rownames
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(rbind, split(x, gsub(".*\\.(.*)", "\\1", names(x))))
#  a.0 b.0 c.0
#0   2   4   3
#1   7   6   9
```